# Python ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

```
line = 'f 1// 2// 3// 4//'
vertices = []
line = line.split(" ")
toks = line[1:]

for vertex in toks:
    l = vertex.split("/")
    #print(l)
    l = np.array[float(x) for x in l]).astype(_DT)
    position = (l[0])
    vertices.append(position)

print(vertices)
```

this is the output ['1', '2', '3', '3'] which is correct! but I am getting a "ValueError could not covert string to float: "      at this line
l = np.array[float(x) for x in l]).astype(_DT)
but there are no leading or trailing whitespaces , not sure how to go about this error!!

when doing print(l) i get ['1', ''] ['2', ''] ['3', ''] ['4', '']

I tried using .strip() on line but that didn't do anything. Also tried replace(" ", "") didn't do anything either. I can't find where the actual problem is. How can I identify where there is white spaces? HOW do i remove the '' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the empty strings in your array comprehension with `if`. You can use the fact that empty strings evaluate as false, and any nonempty string will evaluate as true:

```
[float(x) for x in l if x]
```